# how to add a negative i32 number to an usize variable?

Tags: rust, integer, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

Such as:

```
let mut a : usize = 0xFF;
a += -1;  // -1 may be from other variable, so there can't be a -= 1;
println!("{}", a);
```

The output is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `usize: std::ops::Neg` is not satisfied
```

anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately the error message doesn't help you much.

Comment: Are you stuck with `usize`, or could you use `isize` instead? Or even better, a known bitwidth type like `i64`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. In fact it is index of array, which can only be $usize$

Comment: See also this [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3mcwf7/adding_unsigned_and_signed_integers/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because in Rust, you can only do operations between strictly similar types. Rust does not do **any** implicit numeric cast because it would be a shoot in the foot as you can see below: you have a special case and several ways to have an overflow.

One way to go is to cast the absolute value of the `i32` to `usize` and add or remove it according to whether it is negative or positive. However, you must handle the special case of the minimal value that overflows when you take its absolute value:

```
fn add(u: usize, i: i32) -> usize {
    if i.is_negative() {
        u - i.wrapping_abs() as u32 as usize
    } else {
        u + i as usize
    }
}

fn main() {
    let u = 7;
    let i1 = -1;
    let i2 = 1;
    let min = -2_147_483_648;

    assert_eq!(add(u, i1), 6);
    assert_eq!(add(u, i2), 8);
    assert_eq!(add(3_000_000_000, min), 852_516_352);
}
```

You may also verify the overflows:

```
fn add(u: usize, i: i32) -> Option<usize> {
    if i.is_negative() {
        u.checked_sub(i.wrapping_abs() as u32 as usize)
    } else {
        u.checked_add(i as usize)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let u = 7;
    let i1 = -1;
    let i2 = 1;

    assert_eq!(add(u, i1), Some(6));
    assert_eq!(add(u, i2), Some(8));
    assert_eq!(add(0, -1), None);
}
```

Comment: It seems like the cost of conditional jump is larger than implicit cast. Adding after numeric cast only need to ignore OF bit.

Comment: @ExcosyS.P. The checked operations have a (very slight) cost. However, as far as I know, the explicit cast is not slower than an implicit cast. There is the same cast in both the cases.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood your question: is your number always negative?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Moreover, what I wonder is why not support implicit numeric cast in rust.

Comment: Nope, the number may be negative, its type is i32.

Comment: @ExcosyS.P. An implicit numeric cast is dangerous, because you may have an unexpected result: what if the compiler silently casts a negative i32 to an usize with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)? The result would be more likely unexpected.

Comment: I believe you can get rid of the awkward `min_value` comparison by instead writing `if i.is_negative() { u - i.wrapping_abs() as u32 as usize } else { u + i as usize }`. `wrapping_abs` returns `i32::min_value()` instead of panicking and `as u32 as usize` inhibits the sign extension that would be performed if you just did `as usize`.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for the tip. I have just the concern that it expresses less clearly the logic.

Comment: "Adding after numeric cast only need to ignore OF bit." This is only true if you add two signed numbers, and the carry flag only works for two unsigned numbers. To my knowledge, adding a signed and a unsigned number while correctly detecting overflows can't be done in a single machine code add instruction (at least on x86, which is the only architecture i'm somewhat familiar with, though my knowledge is a bit dated).